# Building a docking workarea - how do i build it?

Tags: wpf, layout

Im making a workarea for my new application the way it is supposed to work is that i have a list of visual elements in a single column in the left hand side of my screen, and an empty workarea to the right. When the user drag a new UIElement from the left hand side to my workarea (maybe a grid og a kind of panel) i want the workarea to show 4 arrows (docking arrows)- i know this does not make much sense when there is only one element. When the user now drags a new UIElement to the workarea i want the same 4 docking arrows allowing me to place the new element to the left, right or above or below the existing UIElement.

I want each of the UIElements to reach to drag drop behaviour as well, meaning that when i drag across a UIElement i want to be able to dock in relation to the one im hovering above, allowing me to build an entire workarea this way.

When hovering a new UIElement on top of an already placed UIElement in the workarea there should be docking arrows both on the item im hovering above and on the outer "grid" allowing me to dock "globally". Ive had a friend of mine record a small video of how this works in another program he is using - it is a similar behaviour im looking for: [LNK REMOVED]

Please advice on how to build this - im looking into DockPanels as that seems the obvious way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avalon dock lib on codeplex? its free

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/documentation